# How can I deploy a unity 2022 3D project onto HoloLens 1?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am using Unity 2022 and am trying to deploy a simple project containing only a static cube onto the HoloLens 1, in hopes of seeing the cube in the 3D space when running the deployed app in the HoloLens. The issue is, after many approaches to deploy the project onto the HoloLens, I only get a static black 2D screen when running the app inside the HoloLens.

I tried deploying the app using the latest MRTK’s holographic remoting, tried running it in Unity’s play mode and deploying the project with Visual Studio 2022 when specifying Release, x86 and Remote (or Device if connected with a cable) as parameters, and the deployment is always successful but still displays a black 2D screen in the HoloLens instead of a cube in the Hololens’ 3D space.
Do you have any idea of what I could do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 2022 does not support developing apps for HoloLens 1. It is recommended that you try Unity 2019.4 LTS and Legacy Built-in XR. Please refer to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20194-lts).

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now with that version! :)